# How to rename bunch of files via terminal, keeping the filenames prefix and suffix and removing wildcard in the middle?

Tags: regex, bash, rename

Given +400 files such as :

```
Remi_Brun_-blablabla_blalala-ASpi777XisA.en.vtt
Remi_Brun_-not_important_but_here_to_nag-ZIBcQ5tMB2U.en.vtt
Remi_Brun_-still_some_wildcard_noise_here-hOxG4g05z4w.en.vtt
...
```

Given this regex match these titles :

```
(Remi_Brun)(_.+)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}.en.vtt)
```

I want to rename my files into filenames such :

```
Remi_Brun-ASpi777XisA.en.vtt
Remi_Brun-ZIBcQ5tMB2U.en.vtt
Remi_Brun-hOxG4g05z4w.en.vtt
...
```

**How to keep the speaker name prefix, remove the variable noise at the center, then keep the finale 11 characters youtube id and the extension suffix ?**

Comment: why do you have 'fr' in your regex? do you want to rename all fr to en too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove everything between the first and last `-` before the youtube id, while allowing for any nonzero-sized language code, then this will work:

```
rename 's/-.*-([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}\..+\.vtt)/-\1/' Remi*
```

[or](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121621) for a more readable answer :

```
rename 's/(Remi_Brun)(_.+)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}.en.vtt)/$1-$3/' Remi*
```

**Edit:**
My earlier answer

```
rename 's/-.*-/-/' Remi*  #didn't account for hyphens in youtube id
```

Comment: Your answer does answer my S.O. question as I wrote it : )
As for my real life situation, Youtube ID may are 11 characters-long and such as `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11}` so it can indeed contain a `-`. Your answer is witty, I didn't though of it and it may be helpful to other users.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it to allow for  `-` in the video id.

Comment: I added my more readable command to your answer given I base it upon yours. I can now accept your answer since it contains both your valid & straight and the readable answers. Thanks you ! :D